# SQLite not unique on a column withouth UNIQUE constraint

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I'm having a hard time figuring out where the problem lies.

I have a pretty much standard db schema

```
CREATE TABLE some_table ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
...
some_other_id INTEGER);
```

The `SQLiteOpenHelper` creates the db normally.
First entry is added normally but when i try to add some more entries i get

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConstraintException: column some_other_id is not unique
```

Already checked `ContentValues` and they are fine (the id is not defined)
My insert statements is as follows:

```
INSERT INTO some_table ( some_other_id ) VALUES (?);
```

and some_other_id set to 0

Any idea why I get this error or when it might occur?

Comment: can you please share full db schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexes marked as unique implement a constraint on a column.

If your other column contains an id it would often be used in a join or filter selection motivating an index for the column.

Comment: Forgot to write that I had an INDEX on the some_other_id field and as it turned out it forced the constraint.